# alternate expressions of the bitwise complement

Tags: combinatorics, functions, logic, binary, binary-operations

I've seen the complement of $A$ defined in three different ways in three different places:

1. $$A’ = (A+1) \mod{2}$$
2. $$f(A) = 1 - A$$
3. $$NOT\ A = -A − 1$$

Are they all correct? If so, how does that work exactly?

Comment: If we set $A=0$ then the first two expressions give $1$ while the last gives $-1$. Unless the third expression is also intended to be taken mod $2$, these are not the same function. If they are all intended to be taken mod $2$, which seems doubtful as there's no reason to negate mod $2$, then negation does nothing and $- = +$ so they are all $A+1$ mod $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A=-A \pmod {2}$, so $1-A \equiv 1+A \equiv A+1 \pmod{2}$ and $1 \iff 2$.

Similarly, $-A-1 \equiv A+1 \pmod {2}$ so $3 \iff 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$A' = (A + 1) \bmod 2$$ is clearly intended to be the complement of a Boolean: i.e. it maps $0$ to $1$ and vice versa, and that's all.

---

$$f(A) = 1 - A$$ likewise maps $0$ to $1$ and vice versa. I don't believe it's intended to have a larger domain than $\{0,1\}$.

---

$$NOT A = -A - 1$$ is bitwise complement in a [twos complement](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system: this means that on almost all modern computer processors it corresponds to a bitwise complement of a full word. Using an 8-bit word to keep the examples manageable, we represent $0$ as `00000000`, $1$ as `00000001`, etc. up to 127 as `01111111`; and we represent $-1$ as `11111111`, $-2$ as `11111110`, etc. down to -128 as `10000000`.

Comment: Aren't they all twos complement though?

Comment: @tjt263, I don't understand the question.

Comment: You said *"NOT A = –A –1 is bitwise complement in a twos complement system.."*. Aren't they all? Aren't all three referring to bitwise complement in a twos complement system??

Comment: @tjt263, you could argue that for the first one, although I would say that it's a one-bit unsigned system so it's meaningless to talk about how it represents negative numbers. The second one is not explicitly a one-bit system, and if you try to use it in an n-bit twos complement system it doesn't work: $f(2) = -1$ but `00000010` and `11111111` are not bitwise complements.

Comment: Ah, of course. I see what you mean by that now. One last thing: Does this imply that (1–A) is equivalent to (A+1) mod 2 ?

Comment: Probably, although the easier way to argue that is to appeal directly to the definition: $(1 - A) - (A + 1) = -2A$ is clearly divisible by $2$.

Comment: I don't get how that appeals to the definition. You've shed some light on it, but it's still a little confusing/unclear to me. That's probably my fault, not yours -- but if you can think of anything to add, or summarize, or something to help us math noobs understand a little better, I'm sure we'd all appreciate it.

Comment: @tjt263, the definition of $x \equiv y \pmod z$ is "*There exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x = y + kz$*"